# addition in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular.js and have a simple question. I am trying to make a calculator that takes input and then adds that input value to a total. However, the scope.add function will not work. Below is my code. Any help greatly appreciated.

html code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="font-size: 35px; text-align: right">
        {{result}} Total
    </div>
</div>

<div class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input">
    <input class="input-label" placeholder="Add" type="tel" ng-model="T" style="font-size: 35px; text-align: right">
    Calories
    </label>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <button class="button ion-refresh button-balanced col" ng-click="reset()" style="font-size: 40px"></button>
    <button class="button ion-plus-round button-calm col" ng-click="add(T)" style="font-size: 40px"></button>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('calorific.controllers', [])

.controller('calcCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.result = 0;

$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.result = 0;
};

$scope.add = function(i) {
    $scope.result = result + i;
    return result;
};

});
```

Comment: You should probably use `Number`s instead of `String`s.

Comment: What is the problem, though

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I haven't used String s anywhere. I think.

Comment: I think the problem (what @RevanProdigalKnight is referring to) is that you are setting `$scope.result` equal to a string (`"0"`). Then trying to add to it. Initialize it like this: `$scope.result = 0;`

Comment: $scope.add will not work. I have no idea why. scope.reset works fine.

Comment: $scope.result is a string, which will interfere with math functions, but also in your add function you are returning the result. That is not needed. Instead you need to do $scope.$apply().

Comment: ok, i see what you mean. i took out the quotes but scope.add is still not working.

Comment: here is the plunker where you can get your solution. http://plnkr.co/edit/1oJcvDQy8TNsXkOcFRe8?p=preview

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the change. http://jsfiddle.net/claywhipkey/e5f546v9/

Comment: Huge thanks @Dinesh Dabhi. your suggestions solved my problem. Sorry about how basic my problem was! angular is all new to me.

Comment: Thanks @claywhipkey also for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.controller()` instead of .controller.

You should also instantiate `angular.module()`. Didn't you forget about it?

Result should be passed as integer not string, so you can't take it in quote.

I can't see your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives. Did you paste your whole code?

Comment: Sorry I left some code. above this I have instantiated .module like this:  angular.module('calorific.controllers', [])

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your variable T in the controller like this:

```
$scope.T = 0;
```